# ActionListener to draw shapes on separate panel

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I want my GUI to draw circles/rectangles on the exact position I coded in the method `paintComponent` when I click on the respective buttons.

But I just don't know how to go on. What should I tell `actionPerformed` to do? Trying for a few hours to figure out a way, but I'm only getting errors.

```
public class Kreise extends JFrame {

    Kreise() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Draw Circ / Rect here: ");
        label.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
        jp1.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);;
        jp1.add(label);

        JPanel jp2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JButton circ = new JButton("Circle");
        JButton rect = new JButton("Rectangle");

        circ.addActionListener(new KRListener(true));
        rect.addActionListener(new KRListener(false));
        jp2.add(circ);
        jp2.add(rect);

        MyPanel obj = new MyPanel();
        jp1.add(obj);

        add(jp1);
        add(jp2);

        setSize(400, 250);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        public boolean circleZ = true;

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            if (circleZ = true) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawOval(150, 50, 50, 50);
            } else if (circleZ = false) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawRect(150, 50, 50, 50);
            }
        }
    }

    public class KRListener implements ActionListener {

        boolean b;

        KRListener(boolean b) {
            this.b = b;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             ?
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Kreise();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated (at this point) but `circleZ = true` doesn't do what you think it does. Also, just do `if (circleZ)`; it's equivalent. Checking a boolean against true/false equality is redundant.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you goal is here - I recommend you clarify. Do you wish to have each button toggle on/off the painting of the respective shape?

Comment: Yes, exactly! My english is too bad to make clear what my goal is precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming I understand the question clearly (you wish to toggle between the a rectangle or circle), in the `ActionListener` implementation you need to:

1. Toggle the appropriate boolean value
2. Call `repaint` on the `JPanel` instance that performs the painting

One way to accomplish these steps is to have a single toggle `JButton`, and pass an instance of the `JPanel` used for drawing to your `ActionListener` implementation, which can be used to accomplish both steps above:

```
public class KRListener implements ActionListener {

    private MyPanel panel;

    KRListener(MyPanel panel) {
        this.panel = panel;
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         panel.circleZ = !panel.circleZ;
         panel.repaint();
    }
}
```

And when you paint:

```
if ( circleZ ){
    g.drawOval(150, 50, 50, 50);
}else{
    g.drawRect(150, 50, 50, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what you are using the global `boolean` variable `b` for But I noticed that you have to call the `repaint()` method when you press the `Button`.

```
public class KRListener implements ActionListener {

    boolean b;

    KRListener(boolean b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //add some code here to change properties of the drawing before calling the repaint method?

        repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where does `repaint()` come from?

Comment: repaint is from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint() He is missing the object that is being repainted though

Comment: I don't know exactly haha, I wanted to use it so the Listener knows whether to draw a circle or a rectangle

Comment: @DMoses, yes, I meant where does it come from in the listener not in general.

Comment: `MyPanel` class has been called and added to the frame in the Constructor `Kreise`. So I think, `repaint()` will refresh the drawings on the frame if there is a change in some parameters `like x-coordinate` and so forth.

Comment: Properties don't need to be change. The buttons just need to paint a circle if Id press the Circle button or a rectangle for rect button at the same exact coordinates every time.

Comment: I see now. I missed that all this stuff was nested together.